# How to enable LightningProviders for GPIO?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to access the GPIO on my custom SBC using Windows 10 IoT Core. I have discovered that I must use [LightningProviders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningproviders) to accomplish this . So I tried to follow this guide to use lightning providers properly.

I used very simple code:

```
            if (LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
            {
                LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
            }
            GpioStatus = "Initializing...";
            var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
            if (gpio == null)
            {
                GpioStatus = "There is no GPIO controller on this device.";
            }
            else
            {
                gpio.OpenPin(1).Write(GpioPinValue.High);
                GpioStatus = gpio.OpenPin(1).Read().ToString();
            }
```

Where GpioStatus is output text on a UI.

I discovered that if I run the `LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();` line outside of the enabled check, it picks up the GPIO controller and lets me detect how many pins I have and read them (All low). However I can't change the DriveMode or write to the pins without error. The error I get just says to `Make sure the LightningProviders are enabled`.

This brings me back to the guide I linked at the start. It suggests to enable DMAP drivers using the Device Portal for W10IoT or DMAPUtil.exe. I have tried both. In the Device Portal the area where it should be is just blank. And in the command line trying to use the DMAPUtil.exe only returns that `dmaputil.exe is not available on this system`.

Therefore I am asking if there is any other way to enable the LightningProviders or if there a way to know if they are incompatible with my board?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Also tried using the devcon.exe commands in the W10IoT Command line.
I am able to locate the Direct memory access controller but when i do `devcon.exe enable *PNP0200` it says it is enabled but remains disabled when checked with `devcon.exe status *PNP0200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm if you have added the **IOT_DMAP_DRIVER** feature in your OEMInput.xml, this feature will add the DMAP driver in the image. If IOT_DMAP_DRIVER is removed from the OEMInput.xml, the Default Driver Controller will be blank in device protal, and dmaputil will be not available on Windows IoT Core. Please see the [IoT Core feature list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/iot-core-feature-list).

**Update:**

You can download the source of [Lighting Provider](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning/), and then deploy and debug in your custom image.

Comment: Tried adding this to the OEMInput.xml and rebuilding the flash.ffu. Booted up and checked devcon.exe and dmaputil.exe and the Device Portal and have all the same results as previously mentioned in my question.

Comment: Have you tested this issue with image downloaded from Microsoft, or flush your custom ffu image to a standard SBC board?

Comment: I haven't done either. I don't have a standard Raspberry Pi/MinnowBoard or anything to test with. By image downloaded from microsoft you mean the image flash.ffu's premade for those boards?

Comment: Yes, you can try to download the image provided by Microsoft and then test this issue.

Comment: Tried to use the ioT Dashboard to install the Intel (Minnowboard (x64)) Image on a USB and run it on my board. It just continues booting indefinitely

Comment: @BWhelan, i have updated my response. Hope this solution helpful for you.